# Pass scope value from Directive to Controller - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a small script with a countdown, created through a `directive`, which starts if a `$scope` value inside the `controller` is `true`. This is the `html` code:

```
<countdown from="3" start-if="{{startCountdown}}"></countdown>
```

Followed by the code of the `directive`:

```
app.directive('countdown', function ($interval) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '{{count}}',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.count = $attrs.from;

      function countdown(){
        var intervalID = $interval(function() {
          if ($scope.count > 0) {
            $scope.count--;
          } else {
            $interval.cancel(intervalID);
          }
        }, 1000);
      }

      $attrs.$observe('startIf', function(value) {
        if (value) {
          countdown();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The countdown is working properly but inside the `controller`, if `$scope.count === 0`, there should be an `alert()` but it is not working.

This is a [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9os05pn8pkVs6YCdYCGG?p=preview) with the complete code. Do you know how to pass the value of `$scope.count` to the `controller` and solve this issue? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: It looks like you are using the parent scope in this directive, i.e. not isolated scope for the directive because you have no scope: {...} in your directive code above.  Which means that you should be able to simply just put a $scope.$watch('count', ...) in the controller to watch for the change to the scope variable.  If you want to use isolated scope then you could put a method binding scope: { countdown: '&' } in your directive and then you can setup a binding to in the controller to that method and then call that method from your directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **$broadcast** to achieve this with same code.

```
controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $rootScope) {
  $scope.count = $attrs.from;

  function countdown(){
    var intervalID = $interval(function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('counterVal',{
          countVal:$scope.count
        });
      if ($scope.count > 0) {
        $scope.count--;

      } else {
        $interval.cancel(intervalID);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  $attrs.$observe('startIf', function(value) {
    if (value) {
      countdown();
    }
  });
}
```

Please find the working plunker [here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/v9hgz4YGZSUTkrSMd6KO?p=preview)

Comment: Maciej solution is correct too, but this is better since it uses the `scope` as isolated. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

**I. Child scope directive.**

You did not created isolated scope, so easiest solution is to remove `from` attribute and init `count` scope variable in controller. So:

```
//controller code
//init variable
$scope.count=3;

//directive code
//manipulate variable
$scope.count--;
```

Example with directive without isolated scope ( child scope ):

```js
var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("controller",function($scope,$timeout){

   $scope.count=2;
   $scope.start=false;//start countdown flag


   $scope.$watch("count",function(val){
   
     console.log("Count is changed to:"+val);
     
   });
  
});

app.directive("myDirective",function($timeout){

   return{
     restrict:"E",
     template:"{{count}}",
     link:function(scope){
     
       scope.count++;//example change
  
       $timeout(function() { scope.count++; },2000);//example change

       scope.$watch("start",function(){
         
            //here we watch changes in start scope variable
            //here start countdown

       });
       
     }
   }
   
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

**II. Isolated scope directive**

You can also do the same thing with isolated scope, it need to pass variable by `=` **( two way binding )**. Example:

```js
    var app=angular.module("app",[]);
    app.controller("controller",function($scope){

       $scope.count=2;
      
       $scope.$watch("count",function(val){
       
         console.log("Count is changed to:"+val);
         
       });
      
    });

    app.directive("myDirective",function($timeout){

       return{
         restrict:"E",
         scope:{
         count:"="//pass variable to isolated scope
         },
         template:"{{count}}",
         link:function(scope){
         
           scope.count++;//example change
      
           $timeout(function() { scope.count++; },2000);//example change
           
         }
       }
       
      
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
      <my-directive count="count" ></my-directive>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your solution seems reasonable, but can you edit the file by also modifying the `start-if` attribute applied to the directive?

Comment: @d_z90 i added in first code example variable start. So create variable in controller then watch it in directive, in callback You can run countdown.

Comment: is the poster not asking how to pass the var from the directive to controller? This show the opposite ie: from controller to directive.